# How to hide icons from Gnome menu?

Tags: gnome

Is there any way to disable icons from Gnome menu?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

From Here http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/speed-up-the-gnome-menu-and-fix-the-annoying-icon-delay/

Note: This is for Feisty (7.04)

> The first problem with the Gnome menu is that it loads the menu icons as needed causing a delay before you can see the icons. By default when you click the Gnome menu the icons are retrieved and loaded after the click (this is why there is a delay) and put in memory so they can be called later. Once the icons are in memory there will be no delay the next time you go to the same menu item. However, I think this is a bug since you should never see a delay in a menu system even if it is the first time you click on it. You can fix this problem by typing the following command as root.
>
> ```
> gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/THEMENAME/
> ```
>
> Remember to replace the THEMENAME with the actual icon theme set you are using. The default is ‘gnome‘.

Comment: I deleted it right after I realised that, then undeleted and edited it.

Comment: He specifically asked about removing the images so thisa is not what he asked for but I agree with NRoach44: this removes the delay and is probably what Andre wants. +1 :)

Comment: thanks. but yeah - i'd rather see them completely gone. it doesn't look like there is an option for that though :(

Answer (score 0):

Years ago we had a switch to do that with but that has been long gone.

You can do this with from the 'propeties' button in 'main menu' in system settings.

[image: main menu]

[image: gimp]

If you can not remove the image here you could delete the menu item you need to remove the image from and recreate it.

Or find the *.menu associated and edit that file.

Comment: and yes I realise this is ALOT of work if you want this for all the images and not just the one you pointed :+

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea.